# Postgres returning strange fractional timezone

Tags: postgresql, go, timezone

One of our tests started failing because of a strangely formatted timezone. The timestamp returned by postgres looks like this: `0001-01-01T02:27:16+02:27:16`. I checked the insert and select statements and there seems to be nothing explicitly telling postgres to use this format or anything non-standard for that matter.

The select statement for this is a long plpgsql function that we wrote in order return a lot of different data points. We wrote this function to remove the need for multiple database round trips. It returns the data encoded as JSONB. This has so far not caused problems but it's possible that this is somehow behind the weird timezone.

The logic of the query is roughly like this: There are a bunch of arguments to specify what should be included in the query. Then it updates sets of uuids to determine which objects should be queried like so:

```
IF include_xxx THEN _xxx_uuids := _xxx_uuids || ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT uuid FROM xxx WHERE content_uuid = ANY(post_uuids)); END IF;
```

Finally we run the actual queries and return the data as `jsonb` for example like so

```
IF include_xxx THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT 'xxx', TO_JSONB(xxx) FROM xxx WHERE xxx_uuid = ANY(xxx_uuids); END IF;
```

If I scan the result into a byte-slice the misbehaving data comes out like this:

```
..."created_at": "0001-01-01T02:27:16+02:27:16", ...
```

I have never seen this timezone format before but have only been using go for about a month so it is possible that unmarshalling the results is somehow the cause of this. I am not sure how to debug and find the root cause and am wondering if anyone else has seen this before. The query runs successfully and returns thousands of results without a problem both in production and for the rest of the unit tests.

The reason the format is an issue is that it seems that out of the box go can't parse the timestamptz into a time.Time:

```
parsing time "\"0001-01-01T02:27:16+02:27:16\"" as "\"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00\"": cannot parse ":16\"" as "\""
```

Versions are as follows:

```
psql --version
13.4

go version
go1.17.5
```

In case you are wondering why the returned timestamp is for the beginning of time, we are using [github.com/jonboulle/clockwork](http://github.com/jonboulle/clockwork) in order to generate timestamps.

Comment: "The select statement for this result is long and difficult to post here" Can you strip it down to a minimal reproducible example that you can actually post here? Along with the versions of the software you are using (postgres server/client, go, ...)?

Comment: @SebDieBln, I updated the description to add the versions and a bit of an explanation of the big query. Happy to share more.

Comment: The format of the timestamp is valid, the `+02:27:16` part is the timezone's "UTC offset specified to seconds". Is that what bothers you? Or is it the actual value of the offset?

Comment: 1) This is not the beginning of time. Postgres handles timestamps going back to 4713 BC 2) `show timezone; US/Pacific`. `select '0001-01-01'::timestamptz; 0001-01-01 00:00:00-07:52:58`. There where no timezones at this point in history, so if I remember the offset is a fudge factor to align the past with the present.

Comment: In the proleptic Gregorian year 1 BC, I think that fractional time zone offsets are just as plausible as rounded ones are.

Comment: @mkopriva, yes you are right. I don't actually care about the format. It is only an issue because it seems that go is choking on it:
`parsing time "\"0001-01-01T02:27:16+02:27:16\"" as "\"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00\"": cannot parse ":16\"" as "\""`

I would be interested to understand why postgres returns the timestamptz in this manner for that particular data point but not for others but to solve the issue it might also be enough to teach go how to parse this correct timestamp string.

Comment: You get that error because the timestamp's format does not match the layout's format, i.e. you're missing the last `:00` part of the offset in the layout: https://go.dev/play/p/XZwbopPQimH

Comment: Reads like [local mean time](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_mean_time), so basically a longitude-based UTC offset, not from a time zone in a "modern" sense as we have them from ~ the beginning of the 20th century.

Comment: @mkopriva yeah I gathered this. So I guess I can replace the sql libraries code that parses the timestamp using e.g. `"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00:00"` as a format (i.e. add `:00`). I can do that to fix our tests. I would much rather figure out why there is one timestamptz in the database with this peculiar timezone. As I said, there are thousands of objects created with "normal" timezones like `0001-01-01T00:00:00+03:00`. Any idea how I could figure this out?

Comment: First take a look at the source column, does the timestamp there have the correct/incorrect format? If it has the correct then the problem's with how you are generating the json in the SQL. If the source column has the incorrect format then it was inserted "incorrectly", i.e. without anything to enforce a uniform format for every single instance of the column.

Comment: In the general case, where you are inserting `time.Time` and then selecting the column as a timestamp (not as json) and then scanning into `*time.Time` you do not need to worry about the format, the `database/sql` package and/or the dirver package handle that under the hood. However when you are selecting the timestamp as jsonb and then scanning into bytes, you are getting the data as is and since postgres can handle different timestamp formats you shouldn't rely on the format to be uniform, unless you explicitly enforce it in your insert/update or select queries.